# How to display overlapped pictures in bootstrap table's cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot successfully display overlapped pictures in a Bootstrap table.

The idea is of course to display several similar icons well distributed on a line.

The code is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.under
{
    position:absolute;
    left:17px;
    top:4px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.over
{
    position:absolute;
    left:16px;
    top:4px;
    z-index:-1;
}

</style>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="under" height="41" alt="Drinks" src="//i.imgur.com/S8t8vOy.png"></img>
                <img class="over" height="43" alt="Drinks" src="//i.imgur.com/zrC8Mxy.png"></img>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c8zn41b3/

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get the affect that you want you can't position absolute both of the elements. Position absolute brings elements off the dom unless it has a parent container of position relative. So, what you need to is have the parent of the img's to position relative to contain the position absolute then position relative one of the img's for you will not get the shrinking table. Then position absolute the other img.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/c8zn41b3/1/)**

**CSS**

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
.under {
    position:relative;
    left:17px;
    top:4px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.over {
    position:absolute;
    left:22px;
    top:4px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```